# What is N/mm² in block characteristics?

Tags: concrete-block, cinderblock

In brick/block datasheet I found strength parameter in N/mm². Does it mean how much weight can a brick hold? So, for example 10 N/mm² of 10x10cm brick could hold 100.000N ~ 10 tons? Is this correct? It just seems way too much (in my opinion). Or does this need some more advance calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, being force per unit area it's compressive strength. Pounds per square inch in our non-metric units.

As such, under perfect conditions of perfectly even loading and adequate support, your 10x10cm brick would hold just over 10 metric tons. Given 10.5 metric tons, or any imperfection in how evenly the load was spread, it would crush.

So, that's an informative number, but not one you'd actually design to. It does tell you that these bricks are stronger than ones rated 8, and weaker than ones rated 12, but any of them you'd expect to design to a safe loading a signifcant factor less than that for a structure you wanted to stand up for a long time. One quick search finds [a document claiming](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Eramirez/CE479/FALL05/DesignSpecifications-Lect3Masonry.pdf) typical masonry safety factors range from 2.5-4, so you'd limit your actual compressive loading to between 4 and 2.5 metric tons on that brick. In most real-world applications, loading would be much less.

Comment: The strength on the datasheet is the maximum compressive stress the block can endure without breaking up. However, in addition to axial force, the building wall will subject to bending due to eccentricity and lateral loads that increase the compressive stress on one side and reduces on the other. Except for the very low barrier walls for the garden, you should seek help from a licensed structural engineer to perform the necessary calculations.